# Understanding differential forms on manifolds (Bachman example 52)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In David Bachman's "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms", in example 52, he lists what integrating a particular 1-form is like on $S^1$. My question is, how does he calculate the ranges for the integrals that he does?

Example 52

Let $S^1$, $U_i$, $\phi_i$, and $w$ be defined as in Examples 49 and 50. A partition of unity subordinate to the cover ${\phi_i(U_i)}$ is as follows.

\begin{align*}
f_1(x,y) = y^2 \text{ if } y \geq 0 & \text{ else } 0
\\
f_2(x,y) = y^2 \text{ if } y < 0 & \text{ else } 0
\\
f_3(x,y) = x^2 \text{ if } x \geq 0 & \text{ else } 0
\\
f_4(x,y) = x^2 \text{ if } x < 0 & \text{ else } 0.
\end{align*}
(Check this!) Let $\mu: [0, \pi] \rightarrow S^1$ be defined by $\mu(\theta) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$. Then the image of $\mu$ is a 1-cell, $\sigma$, in $S^1$. Let's integrate $w$ over $\sigma$.

$$
\int_\sigma \omega = \sum_{i=1}^4 \int_{\phi^{-1}(\sigma)} \phi_i^*(f_iw).
$$

In the next step he shows,

$$
\int_{-(-1,1)} -\sqrt{1-t^2}dt + 0 + \int_{[0,1)} \sqrt{1-t^2}dt + \int_{-[0,1)} -\sqrt{1-t^2}dt.
$$

In general, I do not understand how he gets the range of the four integrals. I would expect it to all be $(-1,1)$. Since $\sigma$ is the entire $S^1$ image and the partitions of unity would limit the integrand to be valid only for the points in $S^1$ that each $\phi_i$ outputs to, I don't see why it wouldn't always be $(-1,1)$.

#### References

$$
\omega = -y\ dx + x\ dy
$$

Let $U_i = (-1,1)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.
\begin{align*}
\phi_1(t) ={} & (t, \sqrt{1-t^2}) \\
\phi_2(t) ={} & (t, -\sqrt{1-t^2}) \\
\phi_3(t) ={} & (\sqrt{1-t^2}, t) \\
\phi_4(t) ={} & (-\sqrt{1-t^2},t).
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\phi_1^* \omega = \phi_4^* \omega  ={} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
\\
\phi_2^* \omega =\phi_3^* \omega ={} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt.
\end{align*}

Comment: For starters, this is not a bona fide partition of unity (since the $f_i$ are not compactly supported). It would also be nice if you had given us $\omega$ in your post. But your assertion that $\sigma$ is all of $S^1$ is certainly wrong; it's the upper semicircle.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely overlooked that! Thanks! That, and realizing that $\mu$ goes in the opposite orientation as some of the other parameterizations made me follow the examples.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I do have on follow-up question: I am not that familiar with compactness (and hopefully, I did not misrepresent the textbook), but is there a problem with the use of the $f_i$ partition of unity as they are? As in, is the example would be invalid or something else?

Comment: I don't know this particular book. Perhaps Bachman is sloppier with the general theory, or perhaps he's just using this to give intuition for partitions of unity (which I certainly don't object to). In general, $f_i$ is smooth and zero before you get to the boundary of its open set $\phi_i(U_i)$. In practice, partitions of unity are important for theory but never for actual concrete computation.